# How to obtain only the positions of the points in vertices of Sierpinski's Triangle?

Tags: geometry, fractals

Mathematica already provides a couple ways to produce the [Sierpinski's Triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiSieve.html), like

```
n = 25;
MatrixForm[CellularAutomaton[22, {{1}, 0}, n]]
```

But I could not find a way to get only the {x,y} positions of each point in the triangle's vertices.

Comment: `Position[CellularAutomaton[22, {{1}, 0}, n], 1]`

Comment: There is a way to cut in some range? For example in the case ```Position[CellularAutomaton[22, {{1}, 0}, 10], 1]``` cut in x axis=8.

Comment: `Position[CellularAutomaton[22, {{1}, 0}, {10, {0, 8}}], 1]`?

Comment: Doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

Answers for the cellular automata variant have already been provided in the comments.
If you want the regular Sierpinski triangle then this works and gives you coordinates in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$:

```
MeshCoordinates[SierpinskiMesh[6]];
ListPlot[%, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: sierpinski coordinates]

Comment: It handles well out to about 9 levels; try this: `ListPlot[MeshCoordinates[SierpinskiMesh[9]], AspectRatio -> 1]`